# Timestamp not showing minutes correctly since user posted,suggestions?

Tags: php

i cannot remember who howver the other day i found a php function on here that i had been looking for to convert my users post time stamp into minutes/hours/weeks since they posted, it works fine all for the first hour and i cant seem to work out why, when a user posts it will say 59 minutes ago and count down to 1 minute then it works as it should from there, any suggestions i will attatch the code

not quite sure on what to try

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Comment: please clarify the problem - I tested on 3 dates ( over 1 year ago, 1 week ago and 4 mins ago ) and all tests appeared OK

Comment: Similar - ran in sandbox as standalone code (no parameters) and works fine: https://wtools.io/paste-code/LBO - suspect it is in the input data.  Can you provide example input.

Comment: sorry so to clarify, the function works perfect after the first hour, if i enter a new post it will start from 1 hour ago and count down untill it hits 0, at 0 after 1 hour the funtion will then count up as it is supposed to, hope this explains it a bit better

Answer (score 0):

To quickly test the above function a simple demo below should illustrate that the function does appear to be working as designed - unless I have missed the point.

```
function time_elapsed_string( $datetime, $full = false ) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach( $string as $k => &$v ) {
        if ( $diff->$k ) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ( $diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '' );
        } else {
            unset( $string[$k] );
        }
    }
    if( !$full ) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}


/* Some dummy datetime values for tests and a randomly generated final datetime */

$dt1='2018-08-18 15:06:12';
$dt2='2019-08-10 15:06:12';
$dt3='2019-08-18 15:06:12';
$dt4=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( sprintf('now - %d %s', rand(1,59), rand(0,1)==1 ? 'minutes' : 'seconds' ) ) );



printf('
    <pre>
        %s -> %s
        %s -> %s
        %s -> %s
        %s -> %s
    </pre>',
    $dt1, time_elapsed_string( $dt1 ),
    $dt2, time_elapsed_string( $dt2 ),
    $dt3, time_elapsed_string( $dt3 ),
    $dt4, time_elapsed_string( $dt4 )
);
```

Example output:

```
2018-08-18 15:06:12 -> 1 year ago
2019-08-10 15:06:12 -> 1 week ago
2019-08-18 15:06:12 -> 15 minutes ago
2019-08-18 15:21:02 -> 56 seconds ago
```

Comment: sorry so to clarify, the function works perfect after the first hour, if i enter a new post it will start from 1 hour ago and count down untill it hits 0, at 0 after 1 hour the funtion will then count up as it is supposed to, hope this explains it a bit better

Comment: i just copied that exact function you posted there and replaced $dt1 with 2019-08-18 16:20:06 and that is showing as 51 minutes ago as opposed to 9 minutes ago.